# Coefficient of elasticity of the spring?

Tags: forces, elasticity

I know this might sound a silly question though
For a spring that is compressed lets say x meters by a force F N. 
what is coefficient of elasticity of the spring?
We are not given the equilibrium length of the spring.

Is it the spring constant then?

Comment: Usually the spring constant is defined as the force divided by the displacement from equilibrium. Why do you think that would not apply here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we remain in the regime where Hooke's law applies, in this context, there is no difference between the coefficient of elasticity and the spring constant, simply given by
$$k=\frac Fx.$$
I think your confusion might be arising from your interpretation of "compressed [...] x meters by a force F N". I would understand this to mean "compressed x meters *from its equilibrium length*", not "compressed to x meters".